# Can node_url be accessed in page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

Calling `debug($node)` in page.tpl.php seems to show that the node object is not fully populated at this stage.

I would like to access node_url in my page template so that I can add certain CSS classes for some nodes without having to use the nid.  Is there maybe a way to access a more fully populated node object in `template_preprocess_page()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) function along with the node's `nid` to get the URL alias of the node without having to load the object:

```
$url = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");
```

If you want the fully loaded node object though use [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7):

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
```

Memory fails me as to whether `node_url` is added to the node object in a `hook_node_load()` implementation or as part of a theme preprocess so I'm not 100% sure it's implicitly available after you call `node_load()`...if it's not just use the first example which will work.

**UPDATE**

On inspecting the node module the `node_url` member comes from `template_preprocess_node` so while `node_load()` will give you the fully loaded node, I don't think it's going to be useful in this case.

In fact looking at `node.tpl.php` and `template_preprocess_node`, `node_url` isn't added to the node object at any point so you wouldn't normally access it with `$node->node_url` but instead `$node_url`. That variable is available by default in `node.tpl.php` but not `page.tpl.php` so you'll have to get it another way (i.e. first example above).

Answer (score 1):

$url = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$node->nid");

The above will return the URL path, but NOT the ?q= if you are not using clean URLS.  Just thought I'd mention that.